# Where is the Google Chrome's personally created search engines bookmark file?

Tags: google-chrome

You can right click the address bar and click "Edit search engines..." and add your own. Where is the file that contains these so i can open it in notepad and edit it myself?

Answer (score 3):

The file is Web Data. The location is:

> Win Vista/7: %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
>
> Win 2k/XP: %userprofile%\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data
>
> *nix: ~/.config/google-chrome
>
> Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

It's an sqlite3 database, so you'll need to have an sqlite tool to edit it.

Comment: Yup, it is indeed in `Web Data` and it is not easily editable, even with a database tool. Believe it or not, it is much easier just to use the official interface. `:-|`